# wrapper class does not match with json resulted from POST request

Tags: json, apexrest, wrapper-class

I have this apex class (coded by another developer)

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/thunder/contapj/*')
global class Thunder_SVC_ContaPJ {
    public static Log_de_Integracao__c log = new Log_de_Integracao__c();
    public static Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ clientJSON = new Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ();
    public static Boolean isConverted = true;
    public static Boolean isError = false;
    public static Integer statusCode = 400;
    public static List<String> validateFields = new List<String>();
    public static RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    public static RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {
        initialize();
        request = RestContext.request;
        response = RestContext.response;

        try {
            log.Nome_da_Classe__c = 'ThunderWebservicePJ';
            String jSONRequestBody = request.requestBody.toString();
            clientJSON = Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ.parse(jSONRequestBody);
            log.Request__c = jSONRequestBody;
            validateFields = clientJSON.validateRequiredFields();           

            // Building Response
            if (validateFields.isEmpty()) {
                setResponse(createClient());
                setLog('createClient', isError, null);  
            } else {
                // If there are any validation error
                setResponse(validateFields);
                setLog('RequiredFields', true, 'Invalid/Missing Required field');
            }
        } catch (JSONException j) {
            setResponse('JSONException: ' + j.getMessage());
            setLog('JSONException', true, 'JSONException: ' + j.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            setResponse('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            setLog('Exception', true, 'Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            database.insert(log);
        }
    }

    public static void initialize() {
        log = new Log_de_Integracao__c();
        isConverted = true;
        isError = false;
        statusCode = 400;
        validateFields = new List<String>();
    }

    public static void setResponse(Object body) {
        response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        response.responseBody = Blob.ValueOf(JSON.serialize(body));
        response.statuscode = statuscode;
    }
    
    public static void setNull(Object body) {
        response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        response.responseBody = Blob.ValueOf(JSON.serialize(body));
        response.statuscode = statuscode;
    }

    public static void setLog(String method, Boolean error, String errorMessage) {
        log.Metodo__c = method;
        log.Codigo_de_status__c = String.valueOf(statusCode);
        if (error == true) {
            log.Response__c = errorMessage;
            log.Mensagem_de_Erro__c = response.responseBody.toString();
            log.Erro__c = error;
        } else {
            log.Response__c = response.responseBody.toString();
            log.Erro__c = error;
        }
    }

    public static List<String> createClient() {
        List<String> erros = new List<String>();
        Id recodTypeIdNacionais = Schema.SobjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Nacionais').getRecordTypeId();
        Id recodTypeIdLoggiOne = Schema.SobjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LoggiOne').getRecordTypeId();
        
        Account existingAcc = (getExistingAccount(clientJSON.cnpj, recodTypeIdNacionais) == null ? getExistingAccount(clientJSON.cnpj, recodTypeIdLoggiOne) : getExistingAccount(clientJSON.cnpj, recodTypeIdNacionais));

        // If there is no Account
        // Merge all similar Leads if necessary
        // update Lead
        if (existingAcc == null) {
            Lead existingLead = getExistingLead(clientJSON.cnpj);           
            existingLead.idLoggi__c = Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.pk);
            existingLead.Phone = clientJSON.Contact_component.telephone;
            existingLead.Street = clientJSON.Address_component.address;
            existingLead.City = clientJSON.Address_component.city;
            existingLead.State = clientJSON.Address_component.state;
            existingLead.Country = clientJSON.Address_component.country;
            existingLead.PostalCode = clientJSON.Address_component.postal_code;
            existingLead.Complemento__c = clientJSON.Address_component.complement;
            existingLead.bairro__c = clientJSON.Address_component.neighborhood;
            existingLead.CNPJ__c = clientJSON.cnpj;
            existingLead.Email = clientJSON.Contact_component.email;
            existingLead.blacklist__c = Boolean.valueOf(clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked);
            existingLead.blacklistModificationDate__c = (clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_at != 'None') ? Date.valueOf(clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_at) : null;
            existingLead.blacklistModifiedBy__c = clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_by;
            existingLead.blacklistReason__c = clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_reason == 'N/A' ? clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_reason : clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_reason.left(255);
            existingLead.boletoStatus__c = clientJSON.Financial_component.bankslip_feature;

            existingLead.LastName = clientJSON.name;  //clientJSON.Contact_component.email == null ? 'N/A' : clientJSON.Contact_component.email.split('@')[0];      
            existingLead.Company = clientJSON.name;
            //existingLead.Company = clientJSON.shared_name;    //clientJSON.name;      PENDENTE
            
            if(clientJSON.loggiEnvios == true){
                existingLead.Status_Receita_Federal__c = 'ATIVA';
            }

            if (clientJSON.averageTicket != null && clientJSON.averageTicket != 'None' && existingLead.GMV_m_dio__c == null){
                existingLead.GMV_m_dio__c = Decimal.valueOf(clientJSON.averageTicket); 
            }       
            
            if (clientJSON.favoredContactMethod != null && clientJSON.favoredContactMethod != 'None'  && existingLead.Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c == null){
                existingLead.Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c = clientJSON.favoredContactMethod;
            }       

            if (clientJSON.segment != null && clientJSON.segment != 'None'  && existingLead.Segmento__c == null){
                existingLead.Segmento__c = clientJSON.segment;
            }       

            if (
                clientJSON.segment == 'Automotivo' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Eletrônicos e Informática' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Jogos e Brinquedos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Livraria' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Máquinas e Equipamentos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Papelaria e Impressão Gráfica' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Serviços Financeiros' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Serviços Gerais' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Serviços Logísticos' ){
                    existingLead.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Mercado Geral';
            }
            if (
                clientJSON.segment == 'Artigos Esportivos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Calçados' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Jóias/Semi Jóias/Bijuterias' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Óticas' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Vestuário e Moda'){
                    existingLead.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Moda e Esportivo';
            }
            if(
                clientJSON.segment == 'Agronegócio' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Alimentos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Cama/Mesa/Banho' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Construção e HomeCenter' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Cosméticos e Perfumaria' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Eletrodomésticos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Farmácias' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Hospitalar e Clínicas' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Móveis e Decoração' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Petshop e PetCenter' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Sex Shop'){                  
                    existingLead.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Saúde/Beleza/Casa/Pet';
            }
            if (clientJSON.segment == 'Top Player'){
                existingLead.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Top Player';
            }
            
            // casos de leads novos
            if(existingLead.Id == null){
                existingLead.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Queues').getRecordTypeId();
                existingLead.OwnerId = [SELECT Id, Type, DeveloperName FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperName = 'Leads_Novos'].Id;
                //existingLead.LeadSource = 'Loggi Envios';             
                
                if(clientJSON.loggiEnvios == true){
                    existingLead.LeadSource = 'Loggi Envios';
                }
                else {
                    existingLead.LeadSource = 'Site Loggi';
                }               

                /*
                if (clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries != 'None') {
                    existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c = Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries);
                } else if(existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c == null) {
                    existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c = 1;
                }
                */

                if (clientJSON.estimatedMonthlyPackages != null && existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c == null){
                    existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c = Decimal.valueOf(clientJSON.estimatedMonthlyPackages); 
                }else if (clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries != 'None' && existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c == null) {
                    existingLead.volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c = Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries);
                }
            }       

            try {
                upsert existingLead;
                log.Id_do_Registro__c = existingLead.id;
                statusCode = 200;
                relateContact('Lead', existingLead);
                return new List<String>{'Lead criado/atualizado com sucesso! ID:' + existingLead.Id};
            } catch (DMLException ed) {
                isError = true;
                return new List<String>{ed.getdmlMessage(0)};
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isError = true;
                return new List<String>{e.getMessage()};
            }

        } else {
            // existingAcc.RecordTypeId = (existingAcc.Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c != null ? (existingAcc.Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c == 'LoggiOne' ? recodTypeIDLoggiOne : recodTypeIdNacionais) : recodTypeIdNacionais);
            if(existingAcc.Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c == 'LoggiOne' || existingAcc.Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c == 'Bling'){
                existingAcc.RecordTypeId =  recodTypeIDLoggiOne;
            }
            else {
                existingAcc.RecordTypeId =  recodTypeIdNacionais;
            }       

            existingAcc.idLoggi__c = Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.pk);
            existingAcc.Name = clientJSON.name;
            existingAcc.Phone = clientJSON.Contact_component.telephone;
            existingAcc.BillingStreet = clientJSON.Address_component.address;
            existingAcc.BillingCity = clientJSON.Address_component.city;
            existingAcc.BillingState = clientJSON.Address_component.state;
            existingAcc.BillingCountry = clientJSON.Address_component.country;
            existingAcc.BillingPostalCode = clientJSON.Address_component.postal_code;
            existingAcc.Complemento__c = clientJSON.Address_component.complement;
            existingAcc.bairro__c = clientJSON.Address_component.neighborhood;
            existingAcc.CNPJ__c = clientJSON.cnpj;      
            existingAcc.EmailPJ__c = clientJSON.Contact_component.email;
            existingAcc.pesquisa_origem__c = clientJSON.Mkt_component.signup_origin;
            existingAcc.boleto_status__c = clientJSON.Financial_component.bankslip_feature;
            existingAcc.Id_Externo_Unico__c = Integer.valueOf(existingAcc.idLoggi__c)+'' + existingAcc.RecordTypeId;
            //existingAcc.Blacklist__c = Boolean.valueOf(clientJSON.Financial_component.is_overdue);
            existingAcc.Blacklist__c = Boolean.valueOf(clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked);
            existingAcc.BlackList_Modificado_Por__c = clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_by;
            existingAcc.ModificationBlacklist__c = (clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_at != 'None') ? Date.valueOf(clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_at) : null;
            existingAcc.motivo_da_blacklist__c = clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_reason == 'N/A' ? clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_reason : clientJSON.Bl_component.blocked_reason.left(255);           
            
//         existingAcc.Nome_fantasia__c = clientJSON.shared_name;                   PENDENTE

            if (clientJSON.estimatedMonthlyPackages != null && existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c == null){
                existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c = Decimal.valueOf(clientJSON.estimatedMonthlyPackages); 
            }else if (clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries != 'None' && existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c == null) {
                existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c = Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries);
            }
                    
            if (clientJSON.favoredContactMethod != null  && clientJSON.favoredContactMethod != 'None' && existingAcc.Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c == null){
                existingAcc.Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c = clientJSON.favoredContactMethod;
            }       

            if (clientJSON.segment != null && clientJSON.segment != 'None'  && existingAcc.Segmento__c == null){
                existingAcc.Segmento__c = clientJSON.segment;
            }   
            
            /*
            if (clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries != 'None') {
                existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c = Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.Mkt_component.month_deliveries);
            } else if(existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c == null) {
                existingAcc.Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c = 1;
            }
            */

            if (clientJSON.averageTicket != null && clientJSON.averageTicket != 'None' && existingAcc.GMV_m_dio__c== null ){
                existingAcc.GMV_m_dio__c = Decimal.valueOf(clientJSON.averageTicket); 
            }
             
            if (
                clientJSON.segment == 'Automotivo' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Eletrônicos e Informática' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Jogos e Brinquedos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Livraria' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Máquinas e Equipamentos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Papelaria e Impressão Gráfica' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Serviços Financeiros' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Serviços Gerais' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Serviços Logísticos' ){
                    existingAcc.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Mercado Geral';
            }
            if (
                clientJSON.segment == 'Artigos Esportivos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Calçados' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Jóias/Semi Jóias/Bijuterias' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Óticas' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Vestuário e Moda'){
                    existingAcc.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Moda e Esportivo';
            }
            if(
                clientJSON.segment == 'Agronegócio' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Alimentos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Cama/Mesa/Banho' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Construção e HomeCenter' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Cosméticos e Perfumaria' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Eletrodomésticos' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Farmácias' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Hospitalar e Clínicas' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Móveis e Decoração' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Petshop e PetCenter' ||
                clientJSON.segment == 'Sex Shop'){                  
                    existingAcc.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Saúde/Beleza/Casa/Pet';
            }
            if (clientJSON.segment == 'Top Player'){
                existingAcc.Grupo_de_Segmento__c = 'Top Player';
            }
                
            if (isfromUra(existingAcc.ID_Externo_Unico__c, clientJSON.Mkt_component.mkt_source)) {
                existingAcc.Origem__c = 'URA Inbound';
            }

            try {
                update existingAcc;
                log.Id_do_Registro__c = existingAcc.id;
                statusCode = 200;
                relateContact('Account', existingAcc);
                return new List<String>{'Conta criada/atualizada com sucesso! ID:' + existingAcc.Id};
            } catch (DMLException ed) {
                isError = true;
                return new List<String>{ed.getdmlMessage(0)};
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isError = true;
                return new List<String>{e.getMessage()};
            }
        }
    }

    public static void relateContact(String type, SObject client) {
        List<Contact> contactList;
        switch on type {
            when 'Account' {
                contactList = [SELECT Id
                                FROM Contact
                                WHERE companyIdLoggi__c =: Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.pk) 
                                AND AccountId = null LIMIT 45000];
                for (Contact ctc : contactList) {
                    ctc.AccountId = client.id;
                }
            }
            when 'Lead' {
                contactList = [SELECT Id
                                FROM Contact
                                WHERE companyIdLoggi__c =: Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.pk) 
                                AND LeadId__c = null LIMIT 45000];
                for (Contact ctc : contactList) {
                    ctc.LeadId__c = client.id;
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Database.update(contactList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    /*public static Account getExistingAccount(Decimal idLoggi, String recordTypeId) {
        try {
            return [SELECT Id, boleto_status__c, Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c
                    FROM Account
                    WHERE idLoggi__c = :idLoggi AND RecordTypeId = :recordTypeId];
        } catch (System.QueryException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }*/

    public static Account getExistingAccount(String cnpj, String recordTypeId) {
        try {
            return [SELECT Id, boleto_status__c, Volume_estimado_de_entregams__c, Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c,Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c, Segmento__c, GMV_m_dio__c
                    FROM Account
                    WHERE cnpj__c = :cnpj AND RecordTypeId = :recordTypeId];
        } catch (System.QueryException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Lead getExistingLead(String cnpj) {
        try {
            List<Lead> ldWithPK = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName, Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c,Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c, Segmento__c, GMV_m_dio__c,volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c
                            FROM Lead
                            WHERE idloggi__c =: Integer.valueOf(clientJSON.pk)
                            LIMIT 1];
            if (!ldWithPK.isEmpty()) return ldWithPK[0];
            else {
                List<Lead> ldWithCNPJ = [SELECT Id,  RecordType.DeveloperName, Tipo_de_Oportunidade__c,Prefer_ncia_de_Contato__c, Segmento__c, GMV_m_dio__c,volumeEstimadoDeEntregasMes__c
                                        FROM Lead
                                        WHERE CNPJ__c =: cnpj
                                        LIMIT 1];
                if (!ldWithCNPJ.isEmpty()) return ldWithCNPJ[0];
                else return new Lead();
            } 
        } catch (System.QueryException e) {
            return new Lead();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isfromUra(String idExternal, String mktFont) {
        List<Account> existAcc = [Select Id
                                  from Account
                                  where Id_Externo_Unico__c = :idExternal];

        if (existAcc.isEmpty() && mktFont == 'URAS') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this wrapper class, also not wrote by me.

```
global class Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ {
  public String pk;
  public String name;
  public String cnpj;
  public Address_component address_component;
  public Contact_component contact_component;
  public Financial_component financial_component;
  public Mkt_component mkt_component;
  public Bl_component bl_component;
  public Vertical_component vertical_component;
  public Enable_component enable_component;

  public class Financial_component {
    public String is_overdue;
    public String bankslip_feature;
  }
  
  public class Bl_component {
    public String blocked;
    public String blocked_at;
    public String blocked_by;
    public String blocked_reason;
  }

  public class Vertical_component {
    public String is_corp;
    public String is_pro;
    public String is_presto;
  }
  public class Enable_component {
    public String created;
    public String pro_from;
    public String presto_from;
  }

  public class Contact_component {
    public String telephone;
    public String email;
  }

  public class Mkt_component {
    public String mkt_source;
    public String mkt_medium;
    public String mkt_campaign;
    public String signup_origin;
    public String month_deliveries;
  }

  public class Address_component {
    public String postal_code;
    public String address;
    public String complement;
    public String neighborhood;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String country;
  }
  
  //public String updated;    
  @AuraEnabled
  public String segment;
  @AuraEnabled
  public Integer estimatedMonthlyPackages;
  @AuraEnabled
  public String averageTicket;
  @AuraEnabled
  public String favoredContactTime;
  @AuraEnabled
  public String favoredContactMethod;
  @AuraEnabled
  public Boolean loggiEnvios;

  public static Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ parse(String json) {
    return (Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ)System.JSON.deserialize(json, Wrapper_CLS_ContaPJ.class);
  }

   global List<String> validateRequiredFields() {
    List<String> validate = new List<String>();
    if (pk == null) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro idLoggi Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(cnpj)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro CNPJ Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(name)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro nomeconta Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(Address_component.address)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro logradouro Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(Address_component.city)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro cidade Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(Address_component.state)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro estado Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(Address_component.country)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro pais Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(Address_component.postal_code)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro cep Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Util.nullToEmpty(Address_component.neighborhood)) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro bairro Obrigatório');
    }
    if (Financial_component.bankslip_feature != CCConstants.NAOMODERADO && Financial_component.bankslip_feature != CCConstants.EMMODERACAO && Financial_component.bankslip_feature != CCConstants.APROVADO && Financial_component.bankslip_feature != CCConstants.RECUSADO) {
      validate.add('Parâmetro Boleto Status inválido');
    }
    return validate;
  }
}
```

This is the Json that I'm supposed to receive as a response of the POST Request

[image]
[image]

And this is the Json that I'm receiving

```
{
"pk": "576010",
"name": "TIZZIANI MOTOPECAS EIRELI",
"cnpj": "19251987000145",
"address_component": {
"postal_code": "87705190",
"address": "AV PARANA 1571",
"complement": "N/A",
"neighborhood": "JARDIM AMERICA",
"city": "PARANAVAI",
"state": "PR",
"country": "BRASIL"
},
"contact_component": {
"telephone": "0576010",
"email": "fernando.diasmotos@gmail.com"
},
"financial_component": {
"is_overdue": "False",
"bankslip_feature": "APROVADO"
},
"mkt_component": {
"mkt_source": "None",
"mkt_medium": "None",
"mkt_campaign": "None",
"signup_origin": "N/A",
"month_deliveries": "None"
},
"bl_component": {
"blocked": "True",
"blocked_at": "None",
"blocked_by": "N/A",
"blocked_reason": "N/A"
},
"vertical_component": {
"is_corp": "True",
"is_pro": "True",
"is_presto": "False"
},
"enable_component": {
"created": "2022-11-08 09:19:11.190067",
"pro_from": "2022-11-03 16:59:51.034103",
"presto_from": "None"
}
}
```

As you can see, the name of the JSON fields of the images, which should be how the data should arrive for me, and the name of the fields in the Wrapper class and in the JSON where the data is actually arriving, as a response of the POST request, are different. Example: blockedAt and blocked_at

And the fields that have the same name, for example: segment, estimatedMonthlyPackages, averageTicket, favoredContactTime, favoredContactMethod, despite having the same name, are not coming in the JSON response.

I am very new at this, so if any of you could explain to me why the name of the fields in the JSON and in the wrapper class are different and, even though, works fine for the most of the fields, but, for the last six fields in the wrapper, it does not bring the data? Please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your url mapping in apex class is
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/thunder/contapj/*')

But in the postman you are not referring to this url. Probably you are hitting some different api in the postman.Make sure you are using same api from postman as well.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but we check and it is the same api. Do you have any other tip that you can give me, please?

Comment: In that case I need to see some debugs and code. So I can connect if you want